Apply options to many controllers
I have 5-7 controllers in Manipulation. Names and ranges are different,
but some options like Appearance -> "Labeled", ContinuousAction -> False
are the same for all.
How can I avoid repetitions of these options for all controllers?

You can abbreviate the options: opts = Sequence[Appearance -> "Labeled", ContinuousAction -> False]; Manipulate[{a, b, c}, {{a, 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.01, opts}, {{b, 10}, 0, 100, 1, opts}, {{c, 25}, 0, 1000, 25, opts}]

@BobHanlon, Aha, thank you! And that works also as {{d, 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.01, otherOps,opts}
